# Really long profile picture disappears from the user profile page

Tags: bug, status-declined, design, profile-page, profile-picture

I noticed that the new profile design keeps the access ratio of most images, so I got curious, made a 40000 x 1 pixels PNG and set it up as a profile picture to see what would happen.

This happened.

[image: Screenshot of my profile]

Comment: "40000x1 PNG" ._.

Comment: Update: I made a 40000x60 PNG and it has my logo on the center so my profile pic still appears when I answer or ask something, but if you go on my profile, you don't see it at all. Pretty cool.

Comment: Its not actually disappeared... its rescaled. 

What the profile has done is scaled the width to the maximum width and with such a long and narrow image, its a black line. righclick and viewthe black line and zoooooooom in to about 500x and we can see the logo there. You might want to change the colour to verify... but I don't think any reasonable person would do this :D

Comment: @JourneymanGeek Yeah, I know, it should have a minimum aspect ratio for the resizing though. (It does have a limit for height, I checked it as well with a really long image)

Comment: There are many ways to break design, kudos for finding yet another one. I'm impressed.

Answer (score 8):

This really seems to be working as intended.  You uploaded a large image, and it was scaled as gracefully as possible to fit the container.  It just so happens that, because of math, that makes it invisible.

If there is a bug here, it's that you're allowed to upload an image with such an absurd aspect ratio in the first place, or that the algorithms for handling non-square profile images are different between the profile page and the user box on the site (I've certainly seen cases where profile images look correct in one but not the other).